# os.system passing a string which contains a variable

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

If I type the following command into the terminal, it works and a message "test" is sent.

```
 sudo echo "test" | sendxmpp -t -u doorbellding -o gmail.com in06khattab
```

I wanted to execute this command in Python, but instead of test it would a variable containing the data and time

This is what I have tried, but they all fail.

```
message="Ding Dong at "+strftime("%l:%M %p on %d-%m-%Y")

os.system('sudo echo '+message+' | sendxmpp -t -u doorbellding -o gmail.com in06khattab') #send hangouts message
```

[image]

```
os.system('sudo echo "test" | sendxmpp -t -u doorbellding -o gmail.com in06khattab')
```

[image]

Comment: To be clear, you don't want a shell, and you don't need `echo`; just run the `sendxmpp` command with `subprocess.Popen`, with `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, and you can feed it the data directly.

Comment: I tried, I got the following output. 
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
 http://prntscr.com/k291y2

Comment: That is not at all what the other answer or my comment suggests. You passed a string, not a list, intercepted stdout, not stdin, didn't pass a thing to the subprocess with `communicate`, etc. Take the time to learn `subprocess` properly; yes it's more work up front, but it's safer, more stable, and more powerful.